# angular 4 crud insert data to mysql db with php

Tags: angular

hi guys why my data save in db twice ? if i submit form the , form data will be saved but it creats another empety row in db too why ?

result is look like this :
 
name - username - email - number
 -   -    -    -

**my user service**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./user";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs";
import { Observable } from "rxjs"

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    create(user) {
        return this._http.post('http://localhost/api/create.php', user).map(()=>"")
    }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./user";
import {UserService} from "./user.service";
import {isNumber} from "util";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    // users: Array<User> = [
    //     new User(1, 'fist', 'last', 'aa@aa.com'),
    //     new User(2, 'second', '2last', 'aa@aa.com'),
    //     new User(3, 'third', '3last', 'aa@aa.com')
    //
    // ];

    users: Array<User>;


    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getUsers();
        // this.destroy();
    }

    create(user) {
        //console.log(user);
        this._userService.create(user).subscribe(() => this.getUsers())
    }

    destroy(id) {
        this._userService.ndelete(id.id).subscribe(() => this.getUsers())
    }

    //  update(users: any) {
    //  const i = this.users.indexOf(users.original);
    // this.users[i] = users.edited;
    //}

    getUsers() {
        this._userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(users => {
                this.users = users
            });

    }

}
```

and here is my child component that emmit data to parent

**user-new.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "../user";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-new',
  templateUrl: './user-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-new.component.css']
})
export class UserNewComponent implements OnInit {

  newUser = new User();
  @Output() createNewUserEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  create(){
    this.createNewUserEvent.emit(this.newUser);
    //this.newUser = new User;
  }

}
```

**and its form**

```
<h3>user new component</h3>
<form (submit)= "create()">
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="newUser.name">
    <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="newUser.username">
    <input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="newUser.email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="newUser.phone">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and here is php file that interact with mysql database

```
include ("db.class.php");

$conn = new Db();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$sql = "insert into users set 
        name= '$data->name',
        username= '$data->username',
        email= '$data->email',
        phone= '$data->phone'
";
$stmt = $conn->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$conn->conn = null;
//end
```

Comment: Does it send two requests?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the error, but you can use a if(!empty(value)) to prevent the entry of null values into database.

```
   if(!empty($data)){ $sql = "insert into users set 
      name= '$data->name',
        username= '$data->username',
        email= '$data->email',
        phone= '$data->phone'";  }
```

This will prevent the insertion of empty database row.